# TemplateExceptionHandler configuration for Freemarker in Dropwizard

Tags: freemarker, dropwizard

Can anyone advise how to register a custom TemplateExceptionHandler for use in Dropwizard?

Jon

Comment: Do you need an exception mapper? If yes then check this -> http://gary-rowe.com/agilestack/2012/10/23/how-to-implement-a-runtimeexceptionmapper-for-dropwizard/

Comment: Do you mean sth. like freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException?